# Change methods to Classes

Tags: java

I just started learning how to write code in java. I want to break up the code into classes, so that each method is a class.  The code is below generates a sudoku game from the solution. Thanks for any help.

Generates a Sudoku puzzle through brute-force

```
import java.util.Random;
public class SudokuPuzzle
{
    public int[][] puzzle = new int[9][9];        // Generated puzzle.
    public int[][] solved_puzzle = new int[9][9]; // The solved puzzle.

private int[][] _tmp_grid = new int[9][9]; // For the solver
private Random rand = new Random();
private short solution_count; // Should be 1



/**
   * Constructor generates a new puzzle, and its solution
   */
public SudokuPuzzle()
{
    generateSolvedPuzzle(0);
    generatePuzzle();
}

/**
 * Finds a solved puzzle through depth-first search
 */
private boolean generateSolvedPuzzle(int cur_cell)
{
    if (cur_cell > 80)
        return true;

    int col = cur_cell % 9;
    int row = cur_cell / 9;

    // create a sequence of the integers {1,...,9} of random order
    int [] numbers = new int[9];
    for (int i=0; i < 9; i++)
        numbers[i] = 1+i;
    shuffle_array(numbers);

    for (int i=0; i < 9; i++)
    {
        int n = numbers[i]; // for the next number in the array
        // if number is acceptable by Sudoku rules
        if (!existsInColumn(solved_puzzle, n, col)
                && !existsInRow(solved_puzzle, n, row)
                && !existsInSubGrid(solved_puzzle, n, row, col))
        {
            // attempt to fill in the next cell with the current cell set to number
            solved_puzzle[row][col] = n;
            if (generateSolvedPuzzle(cur_cell + 1))
                return true;
            solved_puzzle[row][col] = 0; // didn't work, reset cell and try the next number in sequence
        }
    }
    return false; // unreachable (since search is exhaustive and a solved puzzle must exist)
}

/**
 * Solves the Sudoku puzzle through depth-first, exhaustive search, and store the number of
 * solutions in solution_count. Currently, we want to use this only to detect if two solutions
 * exist. Hence, we stop the search as soon as two solutions have been found.
 *
 *
 */
private boolean _solvePuzzle(int cur_cell)
{
    if (cur_cell > 80)
    {
        solution_count++;
        if (solution_count > 1) // two solutions detected. notify caller to abort search
            return true;
        return false;
    }

    int col = cur_cell % 9;
    int row = cur_cell / 9;

    if (_tmp_grid[row][col] == 0) // if cell is unfilled
    {
        for (int n=1; n <= 9; n++) // for each number
        {
            // if number is acceptable by Sudoku rules
            if (!existsInColumn(_tmp_grid, n, col)
                    && !existsInRow(_tmp_grid, n, row)
                    && !existsInSubGrid(_tmp_grid, n, row, col))
            {
                // attempt to fill in the next cell with the current cell set to number
                _tmp_grid[row][col] = n;
                if (_solvePuzzle(cur_cell + 1)) // notified of two solutions being detected
                    return true; // notify caller to abort search
                _tmp_grid[row][col] = 0; // try with other numbers
            }
        }
    }
    else
        if (_solvePuzzle(cur_cell + 1)) // notified of two solutions being detected
            return true; // notify caller to abort search

    return false;
}

private void shuffle_array(int array[])
{
    // swap the first size elements with other elements from the whole array
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    {
        // find an index j (i<j<=array_length) to swap with the element i
        int j = i + rand.nextInt(array.length - i);
        int t = array[j];
        array[j] = array[i];
        array[i] = t;
    }
}

/**
 * Returns whether a given number exists in a given column.
 *
 * @param col    column to check.
 * @param number number to check.
 * @return       true iff number exists in row.
 */
private boolean existsInColumn(int[][] puzzle, int number, int col)
{
    for (int row = 0; row < 9; row++)
        if (puzzle[row][col] == number)
            return true;
    return false;
}

/**
 * Returns whether a given number exists in a given row.
 *
 * @param row    row to check.
 * @param number number to check.
 * @return       true iff number exists in row.
 */
private boolean existsInRow(int[][] puzzle, int number, int row)
{
    for (int col = 0; col < 9; col++)
        if (puzzle[row][col] == number)
            return true;
    return false;
}

/**
 * Returns whether if the 3x3 sub-grid which includes (row, col) contains a
 * cell with the given number.
 *
 * @param row    a row in the sub-grid.
 * @param col    a col in the sub-grid.
 * @param number number to check.
 * @return       true iff sub-grid contains number.
 */
private boolean existsInSubGrid(int[][] puzzle, int number, int row, int col)
{
    int sub_grid_start_row = (row / 3)*3;
    int sub_grid_start_col = (col / 3)*3;
    for (int _row = sub_grid_start_row; _row < sub_grid_start_row + 3; _row++)
        for (int _col = sub_grid_start_col; _col < sub_grid_start_col + 3; _col++)
            if (puzzle[_row][_col] == number)
                return true;
    return false;
}

/**
 * Generates a Sudoku puzzle from a solved puzzle by setting up to 64 cells to 0.
 * (We cannot set more than 64 cells to 0. 
 */
private void generatePuzzle()
{
    // copy solved_puzzle to puzzle
    for (int row = 0; row < 9; row++)
        for (int col = 0; col < 9; col++)
            puzzle[row][col] = solved_puzzle[row][col];

    // create a sequence of the integers {0,...,80} of random order
    int [] cell_sequence = new int[81];
    for (int i=0; i < 81; i++)
        cell_sequence[i] = i;
    shuffle_array(cell_sequence);

    // attempt to set each cell in the sequence to 0
    int count_set_to_zero = 0;
    for (int i=0; i < 81 && count_set_to_zero < 64; i++)
    {
        int cur_cell = cell_sequence[i];
        int col = cur_cell % 9;
        int row = cur_cell / 9;
        int sav = puzzle[row][col];
        puzzle[row][col] = 0;
        solution_count = 0;

        // copy puzzle to _tmp_grid for the solver to work on
        for (int r = 0; r < 9; r++)
            for (int c = 0; c < 9; c++)
                _tmp_grid[r][c] = puzzle[r][c];

        if (_solvePuzzle(0)) // Puzzle allows more than 1 solution
            puzzle[row][col] = sav; // Revert to original puzzle
        else
            count_set_to_zero++;
    }
}

public void showSolution()
{
    for (int row = 0; row < 9; row++)
    {
        System.out.print("  ");
        for (int col = 0; col < 9; col++)
            System.out.print(" " + solved_puzzle[row][col]);
        System.out.println();
    }
}

public void show()
{
    for (int row = 0; row < 9; row++)
    {
        System.out.print("  ");
        for (int col = 0; col < 9; col++)
            System.out.print(" " + puzzle[row][col]);
        System.out.println();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    SudokuPuzzle sudoku_puzzle = new SudokuPuzzle();
    System.out.println("Puzzle:");
    sudoku_puzzle.show();
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Solution:");
    sudoku_puzzle.showSolution();
}
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: You should try to explain better your problem, with more words and less code.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, you should check out the FAQ here http://stackoverflow.com/faq that describes how to formulate good quesitons. In general, questions of this format you have put together (Hey I have code, can someone help me fix it?) are not appropriate. You question needs to be well-defined and limited in scope.

Comment: It seems the OP wants some feedback on how to turn the program into an OOP design, using classes like `Sudoku` rather than `int[][] puzzle`. Better to migrate it to **Code Review**?

Answer (score 1):

Since there is no direct answer to your question, I'll just post a bit of a rant that can hopefully get you off the ground. What you are asking for is much more loaded then "I want to change it from a method to a class" mostly because *it isn't that simple*.

Designing a class is something that takes a good amount of planning and understanding. I'm going to assume the code you have pasted above is working without really going through it and hopefully can draw some examples from it.

As others have already pointed out, you cannot convert a method into a class as classes *contain* methods. But looking at your code it seems you're asking "how can I make this single class into multiple". Its essentially a design question.

A `class`, at a very simple level, often represents a type of real world object. An instance of a class is an `object`, something you can point to, reference, make operations on, create, destroy or otherwise. In this instance a class would be a `Game` or perhaps more specifically a `Puzzle`. Puzzles/games have rules, they have players, they have score, they have time limits and anything else you could represent of the game. Each one of those things is a potential class/object for you to create.

In your code you use a multi-dimensional array to represent your game board. Perhaps you'd want to convert this object into a class? What advantage does this serve? It serves the purpose of separating operations you would execute on the board directly from the remainder of the code.

For example, you have the methods `existsInColumn`, `existsInRow`, and `existsInSubGrid`. These methods are things that operate on the game grid *directly* and should be separated from the actual implementation of the game's executing logic. This seperation into classes helps simplify the code to improve its maintainability, readability, extendability and a bunch of other *abilities*. There's nothing saying the code you have written isn't equally functional, but ask any programmer to pick up your code and see what they could change/improve and they'd turn away remarking "I'm not going through all that!"

Back to the point... once you have a class of `GameGrid` or the like that belongs to a `SudokuPuzzle` you can start making methods in the Puzzle use the logic from the Grid to solve problems. Part of your game will involve taking user input in one form or another and passing it down to the grid. Perhaps a `grid.insertNumber(int x, int y, int number)` call would be all you need from the Puzzle. That method could then call the exists functions above to determine if their guess was right or wrong.

Now, obviously there's a lot more that could be said. You need to first sit down and decide how you want to *design* your game. Will there be `Player` objects? `Score`? Is it a command line game using `System.out.print()` calls to build a grid or a graphical one using a library like Swing? Once those decisions are made, you can put some code down and come back with more specific problems you need to address.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can make a class holding an execute command which does what the command is supposed to do, but you can't convert a method to a class directly. Hope this helps :)